# Passing a "User" object from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a swift app and the task in hand is to send the retrieved "User" object to the next view controller.

It starts with the Sign-In vc, where I make a request to the server and get back appropriate data:

```
import UIKit
import Security

class SignInVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var email_field: TextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password_field: TextField!
    let httpHelper = HTTPHelper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func SignIn_Tapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        // ...
        if self.email_field.text!.characters.count > 0 &&
            self.password_field.text!.characters.count > 0 {
                makeSignInRequest(self.email_field.text!, pass: self.password_field.text!)
        }
    }

    func makeSignInRequest(email:String, pass:String) {
        let httpRequest = httpHelper.buildRequest("login", method: "POST",
            authType: HTTPRequestAuthType.HTTPBasicAuth)
        httpRequest.HTTPBody = "{\"email\":\"\(email)\",\"password\":\"\(pass)\"}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        httpHelper.sendRequest(httpRequest, completion: {(data:NSData!, error:NSError!, description:NSMutableString!) in
            do {
                let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
                if let user = jsonData["user"]! as? NSDictionary {
                    let curr_user = User(
                        id: user["id"]! as! Int,
                        name: user["name"]! as! String,
                        pic_url: user["status"]! as! String
                    )
                    if let mainController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewTabViewController") as? UITabBarController {
                            print(curr_user)
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainController, animated: true)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("error")
                }
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now, all I want to do is pass the `curr_user` object to `mainController`. But I am unable to figure out how.

I have also been doing a lot of searching and multiple people have suggested Delegates and Protocols, but I have yet to find a good and relevant example. So if you are going to suggest that too, please provide some examples relative to my code.

Comment: here is my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33381986/2556515), I recommend using **NSUserDefault** for your purpose, that way users can choose to stay login and logout. once they logout you should empty the value and make sure is optional `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PrepareForSegue, NSUserDefault and Singleton

You have a few possible options to pass your data to other views depending how you want that data to be handled, I will explain each for you and you can choose which one best fit your need.

---

## [**`prepareForSegue`:** Method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/)

I recommend this method if you want to hold your data for 1 segue transition,  it's a good cause to pass this again to another view afterward you need to create another `prepareForSegue` within the new view. here is an example on how to do this:

First, you create 2 variables in both views, 1 to send (`currentViewController.swift`) and 1 to receive (`toViewyourGoingController.swift`).

**currentViewController.swift** `var dataToSend: AnyObject?` 
**ViewYourGoingController.swift** `var dataToReceive: AnyObject?`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    //Check your segue, this way you can transfer different data to different view. also make sure the identifier match your segue.
    if segue.identifier == "toViewYourGoing" {

        //Initial your second view data control
        let ExchangeViewData = segue.destinationViewController as! toViewyourGoingController
        
        //Send your data with segue 
        ExchangeViewData.dataToReceive = dataToSend
    }
}
```

---

## [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Now this method is good if you want to keep your data live as long as the app is installed, once the app is removed this will reset automatically. You also have the option to update the value of the key if you wish, here is how you do NSUserDefault:

I always like to register my NSUserDeafult to default setting,  a lot of people just continue with the second step without registering.

**Register NSUserDefault in AppDelgate.swift**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["valueName": AnyObject])
```

**Set Value** to your NSUserDefault, this depends on what type of data you're storing, should match the one with your registration if you did register. (Example of Boolean data type below)

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "valueName") //Bool Data Type
```

Make sure you synchronize once you set the value to the NSUserDefault, this way it will update instantly, otherwise it will update when it get a chance.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Receive Value:** this will receive boolean value since we set boolean and register boolean.

```
let Variable: Bool! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("valueName")
```

---

## Singleton

Now singleton is basically a global variable that you can use them in any views, but some developers experience some bugs and difficulties, use it at your own risk, I recommend this method when you're definite that you will use that data a lot (STILL RISKY), **but this method is like goddess of data handling** :).

Create a `NSObject` **subclass** and call it `DataManager.swift` (I call it data manager cause it handle data.) as following:

import UIKit

```
class DataManager: NSObject {
        
   //Store Data Globally
   static var someData: Boo! //This Boolean, you can choose whatever you want.
}
```

the `static` is what keep your data live.

Now you can store and receive `someData` from anywhere like you handle any data type like this.

```
//Store
DataManager.someData = true

//Receive 
print(DataManager.someData)
```

---

## Challenges:

You can also use

**[Keychain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YTlXk3Z36k)**
Sergey Kargopolov will walk you through how to use a third party to use swift keychain. Otherwise, you can take even [harder challenge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/) and create one yourself :P .

**[Key-Value Data in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html)**

Comment: well explained.. `prepareForSegue: Method`

Answer (score 1):

In your main view controller add a property to hold the user:

```
class MyMainViewController {

    var myCurrentUser: User?
```

**If you are not using segues,** the `User` can be passed once you have the next view controller object instantiated.

```
if let mainController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewTabViewController") as? UITabBarController {
    print(curr_user)
    mainController.myCurrentUser = curr_user
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainController, animated: true)
}
```

If you are using segues in a storyboard to perform your forward navigation, you’ll need to pass your `User` object in a `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

In your sign-in view controller, implement the following method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MyMainController" {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MyMainController
        destVC.myCurrentUser = curr_user
    }
}
```

The segue identifier is set in the Attributes inspector for the segue in the storyboard.

---

If you want to handle passing the data in the backward direction then delegates and protocols will come into play.

Comment: I decided not to use segues because I failed to understand how to stop them from executing when I didn't want them to. For example, if the user submitted wrong credentials or the server returned an unsuccessful response, then they should not be pushed in the main view controller. But no website took care of that fact.

Comment: There are many variations on segues and it can get complicated to sort them out. You can achieve the same results through code as you already know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable user in MainViewcontroller.

and in this code:

```
if let mainController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewTabViewController") as? UITabBarController {
                        print(curr_user)
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainController, animated: true)
                }
```

you can assign current user to that variable.